# C language linked list problem.. i dont know why next value is not working of create

Tags: c, pointers

i'm noob of C language, so i have a study of Linked list

first, i'll show my code.

```
typedef struct _USER {
    char name[100];
    struct _USER* next;
} USER;

int question(USER** head){
    USER* tempHead = *head;
    USER* a = tempHead;
    while(a != NULL){
        a = a->next;
    }
    USER* b = (USER*)malloc(sizeof(USER));
    strcpy(b->name,"qwer");
    b->next = NULL;

    USER* c = a;
    c = b;

    while(tempHead != NULL){
        tempHead = tempHead->next;
        printf("%s\n",tempHead->name);
    }
    //list(tempHead) doesn't exist "qwer".. why?
    printf("end\n");
}

int main(void) {
    USER* head = NULL;
    //void makeList(USER** head);
    makeList(&head);
    //makeList is working success
    question(&head);
}
```

i think point variable is not reference to "head"..

why?

Comment: What is the purpose of `a` in `question`? After the loop it is `NULL` and you cannot do anything with it afterwards. Do you want to find the tail of your queue? Also, why do you call that function `question`? It seems to be doing an `append` operation

Comment: What does `makelist` do?

Answer (score 1):

This bit

```
    USER* c = a;
    c = b;
```

makes no sense to me. `c` is never used.

## Compiler warnings

Turn on compiler warnings, it will tell you this. I think that knowing that `c` is never used, and immediately overwritten, will lead to finding the problem

Comment: thanks for your help so much! but i think "c" point "a(last node:NULL)", so i have to put the value to "c", then "a(last node) is not NULL and name is "qwer". my idea is wrong?

Comment: That is more a comment than an answer. While the suggested actions and improvmeents are valid, they do not answer anything here.

Comment: @Gerhardh Noes my answer not point to the problem in its first section? As this is a learner, it is not useful to tell them how to fix it. It is useful to guide. Point out the problem.

Comment: The first section is about an unused variable. I would say that is not even close to addressing the problem. There is nothing the OP could do with `c` as they have no pointer to the tail of the list. As a beginner some hints how to do is way more useful than telling thousand ways how not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You simply do not add the new node to your list.

```c
int question(USER** head){
    USER* tempHead = *head;
    USER* a = tempHead;
    while(a != NULL){
        a = a->next;
    }
```

After this loop, `a` holds `NULL`. You cannot add any node to the list with that.

```c
    USER* b = (USER*)malloc(sizeof(USER));
    strcpy(b->name,"qwer");
    b->next = NULL;
```

You do not store `b` anywhere.

```c
    USER* c = a;
    c = b;
    while(tempHead != NULL){
        tempHead = tempHead->next;
        printf("%s\n",tempHead->name);
```

You don't print node `tempHead` but `tempHead->next`. That could be `NULL`.
Also you skip the first node.

```c
    }
    //list(tempHead) doesn't exist "qwer".. why?
    printf("end\n");
}
```

What you need is this:

```c
int question(USER **head) {
// Note: Some error handling in case (head == NULL) would be useful

// First create the new node
    USER *b = malloc(sizeof(USER)); // In C you shouldn't cast the result of malloc
    // You should check for NULL...
    strcpy(b->name,"qwer");
    b->next = NULL;

//Now we have a new node, let's check where it should go.

// First check if the list is empty
    if (*head == NULL) 
    { // Just put it as new head.
      *head = b;
    }
    else
    { // Search for the end of the list.
      USER *temp = *head;
      // No need to check for NULL as we would not be here in that case.

      while(temp->next != NULL){
         temp = temp->next;
      }
      // Now temp points to the last node in the list.
      temp->next = b;
    }

    // Print the list.
    USER *tempHead = *head;
    while (tempHead != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n",tempHead->name); // First print, then advance the pointer
        tempHead = tempHead->next;
    }

    printf("end\n");
}
```